# Is a provider's collecting your PHI and then cancelling your appointment a HIPAA violation?

Tags: hipaa

Suppose someone arrives on time for an appointment, fills out all of the new patient paperwork, supplies a photo of their ID and insurance and is then told by the provider after handing in the material that their appointment has been cancelled.

Is collecting all of this PHI without actually seeing the patient a HIPAA violation?

Answer (score 2):

The [HIPAA Privacy rule](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-45/subtitle-A/subchapter-C/part-164/subpart-E) does not prohibit collection of information, it limits disclosure of collected information. §164.502 categorizes the standard permissions to use and disclose. An example of such information is your name. It is allowed for them to ask your name in order to make an appointment, it is not necessary to wait until they actually see you.